# C++: Overloading the = operator to create an uint8_t compatible data type

Tags: c++, types, casting, overloading

I think this should be rather trivial:

I wrote a class to handle binary coded decimal (BCD) 8 bit values.
The class has methodes like set(), get(), add(), sub() etc. Works perfectly.
Example for get():

```
class bcd8_t {
  public:
    uint8_t get() { return value_u8; }
  private: 
    uint8_t value_u8;
};
```

Now I want to convert this class into a new data type. I basically want to replace something like

```
bcd8_t  a;  
uint8_t b = a.get();
```

by something like

```
bcd8_t  a;  
uint8_t b = (uint8_t)a;
```

So I expected I can write an overloaded "=" operator that returns an uint8_t, like:

```
class bcd8_t {
  public:
    uint8_t operator=() { return value_u8; }
  private: 
    uint8_t value_u8;
};
```

However, what ever I tried the compiler tells me

```
cannot convert 'bcd8_t' to 'uint8_t'
```

or

```
invalid cast from type 'bcd8_t' to type 'uint8_t'
```

How to do this?

Comment: You need to overload the cast operator, not the assignment operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assignment operator is to assign *to* your class.

For converting an object of your class you need to implement a type-cast operator:

```
class bcd8_t {
public:
    ...
    operator uint8_t() const { return value_u8; }
    ...
};
```

---

For all binary operator that you implement as member functions (with binary operators I mean those that take two operands, like for example assignment, comparison, addition, etc.) then the object you your class is *always* the left-hand side of the operator.

Lets take the assignment operator as example. If you overload the assignment operator in the class and do something like

```
bcd8_t a;
any_type b;
...
a = b;
```

then the compiler will convert the assignment to

```
a.operator=(b);
```

It's the same with all operators which you overload as member functions.

Also, some operators (including the assignment operator) can *only* be implemented as member functions. You can't have a non-member function overload of the assignment operator, it's not allowed.

See e.g. [this operator overloading reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) for more information.

Comment: I think you should add `explicit`. Or at least mention it.